# How to add items separated by time delay to listview

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

i have a listView, and as shown in the code i am adding 10 values from 0 to 9. but what i am trying to do is, to add first value of "i" and then wait for 2 seconds,
then add the next value of "i" to the list.

I tried to do that using the below code, but at run time, the App wait for 20 seconds "2 seconds/iteration" and then displays the all the value at once, and that what I do not want.
i want for each iteration in the for-loop, to be added to the listView and to be seen in it, then the App should wait 2 seconds, then add the next value in the 
loop to the list and so on!!

please guid me how to do that?

**Code**:

```
btn_Start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                adapter.add(""+i);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't block your main thread (Thread.Sleep), use Handler or AsyncTask instead.

Comment: @UdiI fine, but i use  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and it shoould show the change happened to the dataset in the listview

Comment: You block the UI thread right after you use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Use a handler to change the UI instead ,putting the main thread to sleep will freeze the UI, which is not a good practice. Handler explained the best way here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJ_pUlWzGsc .

Answer (score 1):

The perfect match for your case is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Just put your code in the doInBackground() and add new value to adapter in onProgressUpdate()

Comment: `AsyncTask` is massive overkill for something so simple.

Comment: provide some arguments than?

Comment: You provide some arguments.  How do you justify starting a thread just to make some small changes in the UI?

Comment: the problem is that you don't try to think wide, why do the guy need to add an item every 2 secs? because he trying to emulate network lag, next thing he will do is to put network code. with your handler.postDelayed you will get a scheduled execution not thread safe!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int count = 0;

            if(count != 10){

            }else{
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);

                count++
            }
        }
    };

    Button btn_start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fab_updates);
    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);

        }
    });
```

Comment: You have the right idea, but the logic is kind of messed up.  Among other things, you're initializing `count` inside `run()`, so it'll never be anything other than `0`.